# How can I tell how many mappers and reducers are running?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a task that is designed to run dozens of map/reduce jobs. Some of them are IO intensive, some are mapper intensive, some are reducer intensive. I would like to be able to monitor the number of mappers and reducers currently in use so that, when a set of mappers is freed up, I can push another mapper intensive job to the cluster. I don't want to just stack them up on the queue because they might clog up the mapper and not let the reducer-intensive ones run.

Is there a command line interface I can call to get this information from (for instance) a Python script?

Comment: how are the mappers and reducers implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that

```
mapred job -list
```

will list all of the jobs currently running, and

```
mapred job -status <job_id>
```

will provide the number of mappers and reducers for each job.

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop Job status can be accessed by following ways.

- Hadoop jobs can be administrated through the hadoop web UI.

  Jobracker shows the jobs detail and default port is 50030 (localhost:50030 in pseudo mode

  Tasktrackers shows the individual map/ reduce tasks and it is available at the default port 50060.
- Hadoop provides a REST API to access the cluster, nodes, applications, and application historical information.

  This REST API can be called from Python script also to get the application status.
  http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WebServicesIntro.html

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for, but I guess if a command line call won't give me the answer, I'll have to go through the REST API. Thanks.